# JQuery autocomplete dropdown menu position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery autocomplete widget in my project. It is working fine expected that the dropdown menu appends to the body instead of the input.
My Codes are as follows:

**html**

```
    <div class="flddiv fw"  id="mealcommentsdiv">

    <input id="foodautotest"  type="text" placeholder="autocomplete">

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getVectors(VectorTypeID) {

Vectortype[VectorTypeID]={}

return $.ajax

({

    url: "functions.php",

    data: {
        method: "getvectors",
        VectorTypeID:VectorTypeID
    },

    method: "post",

    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(result)

    {
        Vectortype[VectorTypeID]=result



        switch(VectorTypeID){

            case 1:

                $.each(result,function(key,value){

                    strfoods.push(value)

                })

                $( "#foodautotest" ).autocomplete({
                    source: strfoods,
                    appendTo: "#foodautotest",

                }

                })
                break
        }

    }

});

}
```

The site uses a ccs grid structure

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The javascript responsible for the autocomplete is  `$( "#foodautotest" ).autocomplete({
                    source: strfoods,
                    appendTo: "#foodautotest",

                }`  You can see the autocomplete in action on [http://wowislandcharter.com/roit2/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, the autocomplete dropdown menu appends to the body. Because of the absence of [`appendTo`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option

> Regardless of the value, if no element is found, the menu will be
>   appended to the body.

By providing the option to the `div` with an `absolute` position solves the issue.

**HTML**

```
<input id="foodautotest" type="text" placeholder="autocomplete">
<div id="autocomplete-cont"></div>
```

**JS**

```
appendTo: '#autocomplete-cont',
```

**CSS**

```
#autocomplete-cont {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var strfoods = ["Bread", "Beef", "Mango", "Salad", "Eggs", "Chicken", "Pork", "Cabagge", "Ice Cream", "Banana", "Rice", "Xmas Cake", "Cassava", "Potatochip", "Chickhen Curry", "Steak Sandwich", "Bbq Pork", "Pavalova", "Calamari", "Sushi", "Roast Beef", "Duck", "Asparagus"]

function getVectors(VectorTypeID) {
  console.log("Got Vectors:", strfoods);
  $("#foodautotest").autocomplete({
    appendTo: '#autocomplete-cont',
    source: strfoods
  });
}

getVectors();
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: contents;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "fixedpart""movingpart";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr
}


/* placement and layout of items in container grids  */

#fixedpart {
  grid-area: fixedpart;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "mainnav""caselabel""case";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#movingpart {
  grid-area: movingpart;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "interviewlabel interviewlabel""interview interview""investigation information";
  grid-template-columns: 450px 1fr;
  /*  margin-top: 195px; */
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px) {
  #movingpart {
    grid-template-columns: 350px 1fr
  }
}


/* placement and layout of items in fixedpart grids  */

#mainnav {
  grid-area: mainnav;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "button form fullscreen";
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 99%;
}

#caseform {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "name""comments""nav""error";
}

#caseslabel {
  grid-area: caselabel;
  border-bottom: rgb(232, 205, 201) solid thin
}

#caseform {
  grid-area: case;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
}


/* placement and layout of items in movingpart grids  */

#interviewlabel {
  grid-area: interviewlabel
}

#interviewform {
  grid-area: interview;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "date firstname lastname age address phone email""gotsick comments comments comments comments comments comments ""nav nav nav nav nav nav nav""error error error error error error error";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#investigation {
  grid-area: investigation;
}

#result {
  grid-area: information;
}

#investigation,
#result {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "nav""display";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
}


/* placement and layout of items in mainnav grids  */

#mainnav>form {
  grid-area: form
}

#mainnav form {
  display: none;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}


}

/* placement and layout of items in casenamediv and casecommentsdiv grids  */
#casenamediv p,
#casecommentsdiv p {
  grid-area: label;
}
#casename,
#casecomments {
  grid-area: input;
}

/* placement and layout of items in investigation div grids  */
#investigatornav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "button""ul";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
}
#mealform {
  grid-area: display;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "date time""provider provider""food food""comments comments""nav nav";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* placement and layout of items in mealform grids  */
#mealdatediv {
  grid-area: date;
  display: grid
}
#mealtimediv {
  grid-area: time;
  display: grid
}
#mealproviderdiv {
  grid-area: provider;
  grid-template-areas: "searchbox""button";
  display: grid;
}
#foodconsumeddiv {
  grid-area: food
}
#mealcommentsdiv {
  grid-area: comments
}
#mealnavigatior {
  grid-area: nav
}

/* end grid setup */
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
input,
textarea {
  border: grey thin solid;
}
.pac-container {
  display: none;
}

/*Color scheme */
.casecol {
  background-color: rgb(232, 205, 201)
}
.interviewcol {
  background-color: rgb(177, 188, 173)
}
.bodycol {
  background-color: rgb(244, 252, 242)
}
.buttoncol {
  background-color: rgb(226, 216, 216)
}
.labelcol {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221)
}

/*End Color Scheme */
#toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0
}
#interviewlabel {
  border-bottom: rgb(177, 188, 173) solid thin
}
#btnfirst {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
#btnlast {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#btnnew {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#mealsdiv {
  background-color: rgb(244, 252, 242);
}
#result {
  background-color: rgb(244, 252, 242);
  border-left: black thin solid;
}
#interviewnavigatior {
  padding-top: 1%
}
.maindivslabel {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  padding: 5px 0
}
.ta {
  text-align: center
}
#mealform {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  border: thin black
}
#autocomplete-cont {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bodycol">

  <div id="container">

    <div id="fixedpart">
      <div class="interviewcol maindivslabel" id="caseslabel">
        <span>CASES</span>
      </div>
      <form name="caseform" class="casecol" id="caseform"></form>
    </div>

    <div id="movingpart">
      <div class="interviewcol maindivslabel" id="interviewlabel">
        <span>INTERVIEWS</span>
      </div>


      <form id="interviewform" class=" interviewcol"> </form>

      <div id="investigation">
        <div id="investigatornav">
          <ul class="buttoncol"></ul>
        </div>

        <form id="mealform" name="mealform">

          <div class="flddiv fw" id="mealcommentsdiv">

            <input id="foodautotest" type="text" placeholder="autocomplete">
            <div id="autocomplete-cont"></div>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="result">
        <div id=navdiv class="buttoncol">
          <div id="uldiv">
            <ul id="resultnav" class="buttoncol"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate the issue as you posted it. I tested the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  var strfoods = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  function getVectors(VectorTypeID) {
    console.log("Got Vectors:", strfoods);
    $("#foodautotest").autocomplete({
      source: strfoods
    });
  }
  
  getVectors();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="flddiv fw" id="mealcommentsdiv">
  <input id="foodautotest" type="text" placeholder="autocomplete">
</div>
```

This is working as expected.

You mentioned your page is using a CSS Grid, yet you did not include any CSS in your example. In regards to the `appendTo` option, pleas see:

> Which element the menu should be appended to. When the value is `null`, the parents of the input field will be checked for a class of `ui-front`. If an element with the `ui-front` class is found, the menu will be appended to that element. Regardless of the value, if no element is found, the menu will be appended to the `body`.
>
> **Note:** The `appendTo` option should not be changed while the suggestions menu is open.

So by default, it is being appended to the body with position so it appears "under" the input field. I think you want to append to the parent, `#mealcommentsdiv` and not the `<input>` element itself. There is no way to test this with your given example as it does not contain all the proper elements or styles.

As the widget creates elements, to display the menu, this cannot be appended to an Input field. It can be appended to the parent and is then positioned to appear under the field.

Comment: I have recreated a minimised version of my site in js fiddle. It still have the same problem. See [ https://jsfiddle.net/sheils/e548hLpd/ ]

Comment: @Sheils I updated your fiddle and it's working a bit better. You still need to adjust the CSS so that it can manage / apply grid to the `<ul>` for `.ui-autocomplete`, but it's appending to the parent properly now. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/w9e7su4t/9/

Comment: For me it's working, when i upgrade the JQueryUI version to 1.12.1. Take a look at my answer and the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hp395zjg/. When you take a look at the console there will still be a `Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function` error thrown

Comment: @Sheils another option: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/w9e7su4t/14/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's even possible to render elements inside an input element. How about to render the dropdown next to the input as a sibling.

**html**

```
<div>
    <div class="flddiv fw" id="mealcommentsdiv">
    <input id="foodautotest" type="text" placeholder="autocomplete">

    <!-- let's take this one as parent-->
    <div id="autocomplete-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$( "#foodautotest" ).autocomplete({
    source: strfoods,
    appendTo: "#autocomplete-wrapper",
});
```

If this does not fit your needs please add more informations to the question why you need to append the dropdown to the input element.

**EDIT:** Please make sure that your JQuery and JQueryUI is up to date, because there are some incompatibilities that caused errors in JQuerys `offset` function.

See here: https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/issues/132

**Currently** the latest versions are:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
```